# Android: adb pull command not working/stuck

Tags: android, adb, pull

on Linux machine I'm able to push files to my Motorla one zoom XT2010-1 via adb yet when I try to pull, the  [command is stuck indefinitely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mENl8.png). The paths seems to be correct since TAB autofill kicks in, and file is created in destionation directory.

`adb pull /sdcard/Download/magisk_patched-25200_QsXC2.img /home/flap/Downloads/`

Comment: What about other commands like `adb devices` `adb shell` and so on Do they work so is it an adb problem or a path problem. Have you tried `adb kill-server` ?